# Binding to function, which get result from $http.get

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I have list of checkbox and want return some statistic from server for selected.

View

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <input ng-model="regionId">
    {{getStatistic()}}
</div>
```

Controller

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.regionId = 'abc';

    $scope.getStatistic = function() {
        $http.get('serviceUrl', {params:$scope.regionId}).success(
            function(data){
                return data;
            });

        //How return data to view?

    }
});
```

How I can declare function getStatistic() in controller. The function must request web-service and return a string after each change of model.

Best,
Evgeniy.

Comment: show us your controller code.And the url of the source from where you want's to get data. Your url accept data in get or post form?

Comment: I change example and add some info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the value is changed you want to call the webservice to fetch the result.

```
$scope.toggle = function(region) {
  $http.get('service/resulturl')
       .success(function(result) {
          $scope.statistic = result;
        });
};
```

As you can see the result of the webservice call is stored in $scope.statistic. This is all you need to bind to in the view :

```
SUMMARY: {{statistic}}
```

EDIT:

Rather than rely on an onChange event, you can [watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#methods_%24watch) your model for changes:

```
$scope.$watch('regionId', function() {
    $http.get('service/resulturl')
       .success(function(result) {
          $scope.statistic = result;
        });
});
```

If you want to watch an array of values pass a third parameter of `true` to the $watch function to do a value comparison rather than a reference comparison.

FURTHER EDIT:

Have seen your amended example. You would not want to put the GetStatistic() call in the view as this would trigger an http get every cycle which would be completely unnecessary. You should bind to a value that is set when the value you are watching changes and only trigger the http get when the value changes.

Comment: My model can change from other place. I wouldn't set ng-click in every place.

Comment: @GraDea in that case using a $watch would probably be a better way to go.